# Insert a row when clicks on a tile

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angular and I would like to display elements of a list in 2 columns. Then, when I click on a 'tile', I would like a row to be inserted beneath but without changing actual rows.

So for example, if I have this table

```
| 1 | 2 |
|---|---|
| 3 | 4 |
```

When I click on tile '1' or '2', I would like to have the following where R is the new row :

```
| 1   | 2  |
|-----|----|
|     R    |
|-----|----|
| 3   | 4  |
```

I tried with the following code :

```
<div class="row>
        <div class="col-6" *ngFor="let element of list">
                {{ element.myContent }}
                <div class="row" *ngIf='myCondition'>
                        {{ myNewRow }}
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Of course, the output is

```
| 1   | 2  |
|-----|----|
|  R  |    |
|-----|----|
| 3   | 4  |
```

```
<div class="row>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let element of list">
                <div class="col-6">
                        {{ element.myContent }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-12" *ngIf='myCondition'>
                        {{ myNewRow }}
                </div>
        </ng-container>
</div>
```

The output is the one I want when I click on a tile in the right column.
But with the tile 1 on the left column the output is :

```
| 1   | 
|-----|----|
|     R    |
|-----|----|
| 2   | 3  |
|-----|----|
| 4   |
```

I understand why I get all those outputs. But is there a way I can get the output I would like ?

Comment: Good description, i have one question, so your newly added row should also have 2 columns? or only one large?

Comment: The new row should have 1 large column

Answer (score 0):

So basically you **need to operate on data not on html**, so when you add a row, you **need to add it to your array** and it will be rendered by directive. And you **need to add boolean flag** to item that shows whether **it's one column row** or not.

### Html template

```
<div class="row>
        <ng-contanier *ngFor="let element of list; index as i">
                <div [ngClass]="getClass(i)" (click)="onCellClick(i)">
                      {{ element.myContent }}
                </div>
        </ng-container>
</div>
```

### Ts file

```
.....
list: any[];
.....
getClass(i: number): string {
   // here you will have new flag at each item that indicates whether it's one column row
   return this.list[i].oneColumnRow ? 'col-12' : 'col-6';
}
.....
onCellClick(i: number): void {
   // here you just add new row with custom content and one-column-row flag set to true
   const newRow = { myContent: 'content', oneColumnRow: true };
   this.list.splice(i+1, 0, newRow);
}
......
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot ! Glad to know it can't be done only with html

Comment: I have just go around to try your solution.The result is the same as my last attempt. When I do this.list.splice(i + 1, ..., ...), it will add the new row just after. But if my tile is on the left, it need to be this.list.splice(i + 2, ..., ...). And checking if my tile index %2 = 1 or 0 doesn't seem very clean.